# How to use NDB's id property?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

With old datastore I've used keys. Now I have to use ids (taken from [NDB Cheat Sheet doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qGgoBlSvd3sUxz2PgWJVeEHBRPzsLh-haHConITDHZU/edit)):

```
user = User.get_by_id(user_id)
if user is None:
    user = User(id=user_id)
```

But looks like this code doesn't work - the record is added several times.

(user_id is String in my case)

Comment: how do you create the entities? do they have a parent?

Comment: @aschmid00, the code in the question contains creation of the entity - please see line 3 there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason, my code above is correct, but my class contained id property:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    id = ndb.StringProperty()
```

and it was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

See the section 'Building a Key' of the NDB Cheat Sheet.

```py
user = ndb.Key('User', user_id).get()
if user is None:
  user = User(id=user_id)
```

or try this and let me know if it works:

```py
user = User.get_by_id(user_id)
  if user is None:
  user = User(id=user_id)
```

BTW even if user_id is a string you should use `'%s' % user_id`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a transactional operation:

```
user = User.get_or_insert(user_id)
```